# how to insert date and time in database table using matlab database toolbox

Tags: mysql, sql, matlab, database-connection

Is it possible to insert the current time in table using the code `datestr(now);`?

I am getting this error:

```
Error using database/fastinsert (line 86) Input data must be a cell array, matrix, or structure

Error in licenseplate>pushbutton23_Callback (line 615) fastinsert(conn,tableName,colnames2,txt);
```

in the command window.

Here's the code:

```
conn = database('vlmsystem','admin','admin');
dbpath = 'C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Documents\Task\0.1 Systems\System 1 - edited\Appendix\vlogdbase.mdb';
tableName = 'vehicleLog';
colnames = {'plate_number','date_time','login_logout'};
colnames1 = {'plate_number'};
colnames2 = {'date_time'};
colnames3 = {'login_logout'};
txt = datestr(now);
fastinsert(conn,tableName,colnames2,txt);
close(conn);
```

**EDIT using txt = {datestr(now)} :**

I'm getting this error and it's not recording the date in the table.

> > licenseplate
>
> txt =
>
> ```
> '25-Oct-2013 02:03:59'
> ```

```
Error using database/datainsert (line 129)
Unable to insert element in row 1 column 1, 25-Oct-2013 02:03:59.
Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Error in licenseplate>pushbutton23_Callback (line 615)
datainsert(conn,tableName,colnames2,txt);
```

Comment: Have you tried following the suggestion in the error-message, putting the datestring into a cell-array?: `txt = {datestr(now)}`

Comment: Tried doing the suggestion but still, it's not exporting the data into the table.

Comment: @sebastian is there a way to change the format of the date and time? I think the current format is dd-mm-yyy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the `datestr` according to your database.
How to format datestrings is described in the `datestr` docs.
You can almost copy&paste that from the last error message:

`txt = {datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS')}`

should be fine.